# User Permisssions White List vs Black List

Tags: oracle, permissions, plsql

I have Applications, Roles, Users, Permissions, Application_Permissions, User_Permissions, Role_Permissions, Application_Roles and Role_Permissions tables. So, permission can be defined at application level, role level and user level. Let's say `User A` belongs to `Application X` and `Application X` can have `XX Permission`. So, `User A` will get `XX Permission`. Now, I want to give all users of `Application B` with `XX Permission` but except `User B`. How can I fit this with my current design?

```
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION_PERMISIONS (APPLICATION_PERMISION_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, APPLICATION_ID number(15), PERMISION_DEFINITION_ID number(15)CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_APPLICATION_PERMISIONS PRIMARY KEY (APPLICATION_PERMISION_ID));
CREATE TABLE APPLICATION_ROLES (APPLICATION_ROLE_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, APPLICATION_ID number(15), ROLE_ID number(15)CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_APPLICATION_ROLES PRIMARY KEY (APPLICATION_ROLE_ID));
CREATE TABLE APPLICATIONS (APPLICATION_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, CODE varchar2(30), NAME_AR varchar2(255), NAME_EN varchar2(255), START_DATE date, END_DATE date CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_APPLICATIONS PRIMARY KEY (APPLICATION_ID));
CREATE TABLE PERMISION_DEFINITIONS (PERMISION_DEFINITION_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, CODE varchar2(30), NAME_AR varchar2(255), NAME_EN varchar2(255), START_DATE date, END_DATE date CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_PERMISION_DEFITIONS PRIMARY KEY (PERMISION_DEFINITION_ID));
CREATE TABLE ROLE_PERMISSIONS (ROLE_PERMISSION_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, ROLE_ID number(15), PERMISION_DEFINITION_ID number(15), START_DATE date, END_DATE date CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_ROLE_PERMISSIONS PRIMARY KEY (ROLE_PERMISSION_ID));
CREATE TABLE ROLES (ROLE_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, CODE varchar2(30) NOT NULL, NAME_AR varchar2(255), NAME_EN varchar2(255), START_DATE date, END_DATE date CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_ROLES PRIMARY KEY (ROLE_ID));
CREATE TABLE USER_PERMISSIONS (USER_PERMISSION_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, USER_ID number(15), PERMISION_DEFINITION_ID number(15)CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_USER_PERMISSIONS PRIMARY KEY (USER_PERMISSION_ID));
CREATE TABLE USER_ROLES (USER_ROLE_ID number(15) GENERATED AS IDENTITY, USER_ID number(15), ROLE_ID number(15)CONSTRAINT PK_SEC_USER_ROLES PRIMARY KEY (USER_ROLE_ID));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two different user roles: one with the permission granted for most users, and one without the permission for User B.

In the world of security, grants or permissions should *always* be assigned according to the principle of least privilege (only what the user absolutely needs to do their job). As such, privileges should *always* be denied by default and assigned explicitly, as with a whitelist. They should never be assigned by default and blocked individually (blacklist). Implicit privileges, especially when combined with explicit ones, are more difficult to audit and troubleshoot. Keep it simple.

Comment: I have created denied tables(like ROLE_DENIED_PERMISSIONS) which took precedence over the all permissions.

Comment: Permissions should always be explicitly granted, not implicitly granted and then explicitly denied. Your approach is inefficient and prone to error in enforcement and auditing.

Comment: This is why DENIED table(s) created. So, what table structure should we follow?

Comment: I'm saying don't do "denied" at all. *Everything* should be denied by default. Only ever grant what is needed; never grant and then deny. Have two roles with different grants for each type of user.

Comment: What if User have XY role and XY role have specific permission. Shouldn't all users of XY role get this permission. If yes what I want all users of XY role except ABC user?

Comment: Then ABC user needs a separate role, with only the correct permissions. Only ever grant the bare minimum of what is needed; never grant and then deny/take away.